# How to get the meta value of the ACF field (wordpress)?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to get the meta value of the ACF field.
ACF field called 'submitdate' (format => Date Time picker : Y-m-d H:i:s) already has data '2021-06-11 17:23:36' 
I tried the following code, but it only shows correct $post->ID, it doesn't show $submitdate.
No error in console.
Would you please let me know how to echo the value of the field?

Query I tried:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'         => 'project',
'posts_per_page'    => -1,
'author'            => get_current_user_id(),
'name'              => get_the_title()
    );
$query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
    global $post;
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $submitdate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'submitdate', true);
echo $post->ID;
echo $submitdate; 
  }
}
```

I also tried, it shows current date and time, not the value in the field:

```
$submitdate = get_field("submitdate", $post->ID);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* I had same issue before few days and resolved with below function */

/* please try this line of code */
    
  $args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'project',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'author'            => get_current_user_id(),
    'name'              => get_the_title()
   );
  $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
    global $post;
   
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
         $query->the_post();
         $submitdate = get_field('submitdate', $post->ID ); // if changed field name then update key in this query

          echo $post->ID;
          echo $submitdate; 
     }
   }
```

Comment: Hi: Thank you for your help. I tried it but it shows current date and time, not the value in the field. Would you please let me know how to solve the problem? Thank you.

Comment: may be variable conflict. you can change variable name and try

Comment: are you sure? your key and post id is correct?

Comment: Hi, I changed the field name (unique name in ACF), but still it shows current time....

Comment: what is the value in DB? for the post->ID you trying to fetch?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a newbie, I'm not sure if I understooed your question correctly. Post ID shows :17190, I echoed it to see if the code works.

Comment: can you please check in database for postid = 17190 and check value there. it is for confirming that we have value in db or it's blank

Comment: Yeah, I checked, and it has data => 2021-06-11 17:23:36

Comment: Hi wpdevloper_j: Thank you a lot for your supportive help. I fond something strage. I set Date Time picker : Y-m-d H:i:s, for the ACF field called 'submitdate'. I used $value_date = current_datetime(); to save the value automatically when save the post. What I found it that the time in the field changes. It keeps current time... Your code works very well, just the field has problem, I think...

Comment: if above answer is correct according to your question then mark as resolved so other user can try if have same issue if future

Comment: Hi wpdevloper_j , yep, I did it, thank you.